# Should weak reference be passed or created inside the method?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a simple question here.

I want to know if there is any preference of one over another. If yes, why?

Following is a method of some class with `mListener` as member variable.

```
WeakReference<Listener> mListener;

public void register(WeakReference<Listener> listener) {
  mListener = listener;
}
```

over

```
public void register(Listener listener) {
  mListener = new WeakReference<Listener>(listener); 
}
```

Comment: This is opinion-based and depends on relative style preferences. However, as much as **contracts** matter, only the developer knows the responsibilities left to the caller. So no one can objectively answer this question.

Comment: To be frank, I actually prefer the second example. If we have a codebase where we pass along objects across methods, so better we pass the strong reference and wherever the object is actually consumed, create a weak reference there, let the method have the responsibility of deciding whether it should have a weak or strong reference and on top of that -- its cleaner. Well, that's just me.

Comment: This is opinion based, my opinion goes *definitely* for the second option.
You normally want to *minimize* leaking implementation details. The caller should neither know nor really care if listeners are wrapped in weak references. It should not be callers responsibility to do this wrapping.